# Denormalize data is pyspark if column is having null values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like below

```
# create data frame
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[
("SAM", "2021-03-04", "FULL", "", ""),
("TIM", "2021-03-04", "", "YES", ""),
("JIM", "2021-03-06", "HALF", "NO", "YES"),
("RAM", "", "FULL", "", ""),
("ROB", "2021-03-11", "FULL", "NO", ""),
("BOB", "2021-03-14", "", "NO", ""),
("TOM", "2021-03-11", "", "NO", "YES")
],
("user", "date", "type", "legal", "authorized"))
```

Output is below

```
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
|user|      date|type|legal|authorized|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
| SAM|2021-03-04|FULL| null|      null|
| TIM|2021-03-04|null|  YES|      null|
| JIM|2021-03-06|HALF|   NO|       YES|
| RAM|      null|FULL| null|      null|
| ROB|2021-03-11|FULL|   NO|      null|
| BOB|2021-03-14|null|   NO|      null|
| TOM|2021-03-11|null|   NO|       YES|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+

# columns list to check
list_columns = ['type', 'legal', 'authorized']
```

I want to denormalise the data is such a way that if columns `type, legal, authorized` are having null values then do the below

```
For each record where the `type, legal, authorized` is null the create a new record for that column
```

For example

```
record where `user`= `SAM`, `legal` and `authorized` columns are null. so I want a new data frame to have below values 

+----+----------+----------+------------------+
|user|      date|  col_name|            reason|
+----+----------+----------+------------------+
| SAM|2021-03-04|     legal|     legal is NULL|
| SAM|2021-03-04|authorized|authorized is NULL|
+----+----------+----------+------------------+
```

Similarly, I want it for all the records.
For record `RAM` the `date` is NULL so I don't need a record for `date` column as it is not in the list of columns I need to check

Final expected output is below

```
+----+----------+----------+------------------+
|user|      date|  col_name|            reason|
+----+----------+----------+------------------+
| SAM|2021-03-04|     legal|     legal is NULL|
| SAM|2021-03-04|authorized|authorized is NULL|
| TIM|2021-03-04|      type|      type is NULL|
| TIM|2021-03-04|authorized|authorized is NULL|
| RAM|          |     legal|     legal is NULL|
| RAM|          |authorized|authorized is NULL|
| ROB|2021-03-11|authorized|authorized is NULL|
| BOB|2021-03-14|      type|      type is NULL|
| BOB|2021-03-14|authorized|authorized is NULL|
| TOM|2021-03-11|     legal|     legal is NULL|
+----+----------+----------+------------------+
```

I have tried like below. I am able to filter the null records but

```
df_type = df.where(df.type.isNull())
```

output

```
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
|user|      date|type|legal|authorized|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
| TIM|2021-03-04|null|  YES|      null|
| BOB|2021-03-14|null|   NO|      null|
| TOM|2021-03-11|null|   NO|       YES|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+

df_legal = df.where(df.legal.isNull())

+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
|user|      date|type|legal|authorized|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
| SAM|2021-03-04|FULL| null|      null|
| RAM|      null|FULL| null|      null|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+

df_authorized = df.where(df.authorized.isNull())

+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
|user|      date|type|legal|authorized|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
| SAM|2021-03-04|FULL| null|      null|
| TIM|2021-03-04|null|  YES|      null|
| RAM|      null|FULL| null|      null|
| ROB|2021-03-11|FULL|   NO|      null|
| BOB|2021-03-14|null|   NO|      null|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
```

I tried to do it in a loop as well like below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

for i in list_columns:
    df = df.where(f.col(i).isNull())
```

But received

```
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
|user|      date|type|legal|authorized|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the correct idea, but you're replacing the dataframes in each iteration of the for loop, which led to no results. Instead, you can create a list of dataframes for each item in `list_columns`, and combine them to a single dataframe using `unionAll`.

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

list_columns = ['type', 'legal', 'authorized']
dfs = []

for i in list_columns:
    dfs.append(
        df.where(df[i].isNull())
          .selectExpr('user', 'date', '"%s" as col_name' % i, '"%s is NULL" as reason' % i)
    )

result = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

result.show()
+----+----------+----------+------------------+
|user|      date|  col_name|            reason|
+----+----------+----------+------------------+
| TIM|2021-03-04|      type|      type is NULL|
| BOB|2021-03-14|      type|      type is NULL|
| TOM|2021-03-11|      type|      type is NULL|
| SAM|2021-03-04|     legal|     legal is NULL|
| RAM|      null|     legal|     legal is NULL|
| SAM|2021-03-04|authorized|authorized is NULL|
| TIM|2021-03-04|authorized|authorized is NULL|
| RAM|      null|authorized|authorized is NULL|
| ROB|2021-03-11|authorized|authorized is NULL|
| BOB|2021-03-14|authorized|authorized is NULL|
+----+----------+----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop on each column, you can unpivot the dataframe using `stack` function then simply filter those with null values and create column `reason` using concat:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.selectExpr(
    "user", 
    "date",
    "stack(3, 'type', type, 'legal', legal, 'authorized', authorized) as (col_name, reason)"
).filter(
    "reason is null"
).withColumn("reason", F.concat(F.col("col_name"), F.lit(" is NULL")))

df1.show()
#+----+----------+----------+------------------+
#|user|      date|  col_name|            reason|
#+----+----------+----------+------------------+
#| SAM|2021-03-04|     legal|     legal is NULL|
#| SAM|2021-03-04|authorized|authorized is NULL|
#| TIM|2021-03-04|      type|      type is NULL|
#| TIM|2021-03-04|authorized|authorized is NULL|
#| RAM|      null|     legal|     legal is NULL|
#| RAM|      null|authorized|authorized is NULL|
#| ROB|2021-03-11|authorized|authorized is NULL|
#| BOB|2021-03-14|      type|      type is NULL|
#| BOB|2021-03-14|authorized|authorized is NULL|
#| TOM|2021-03-11|      type|      type is NULL|
#+----+----------+----------+------------------+
```

---

Another way by creating array of structs using list comprehension on `list_columns` then explode it after filtering null elements :

```
# columns list to check
list_columns = ['type', 'legal', 'authorized']

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "null_cols",
    F.array(*[
        F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), F.struct(F.lit(c).alias("col_name"), F.lit(f"{c} is NULL").alias("reason")))
        for c in list_columns
    ])
)).selectExpr("user", "date", "inline(filter(null_cols, x -> x is not null))")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when().otherwise()` SQL function or `case` statement in SQL.
Online code @ https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/8963851468310921/90827306160555/5846184720595634/latest.html

```
df.withColumn("reason", F.
              when(F.col("date").isNull(), "date is Null").
              when(F.col("type").isNull(), "type is Null").
              when(F.col("legal").isNull(), "legal is Null").
              when(F.col("authorized").isNull(), "authorized is Null").
              otherwise(None)) \
.withColumn("column_name", F.
              when(F.col("date").isNull(), "date").
              when(F.col("type").isNull(), "type").
              when(F.col("legal").isNull(), "legal").
              when(F.col("authorized").isNull(), "authorized").
              otherwise(None)).show()

+----+----------+----+-----+----------+------------------+-----------+
|user|      date|type|legal|authorized|            reason|column_name|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+------------------+-----------+
| SAM|2021-03-04|FULL| null|      null|     legal is Null|      legal|
| TIM|2021-03-04|null|  YES|      null|      type is Null|       type|
| JIM|2021-03-06|HALF|   NO|       YES|              null|       null|
| RAM|      null|FULL| null|      null|      date is Null|       date|
| ROB|2021-03-11|FULL|   NO|      null|authorized is Null| authorized|
| BOB|2021-03-14|null|   NO|      null|      type is Null|       type|
| TOM|2021-03-11|null|   NO|       YES|      type is Null|       type|
+----+----------+----+-----+----------+------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Here for example for user `SAM` I have null values in `legal` and `authorized` columns so I am expecting two records. But your answer is giving only one record.

Comment: I was not checking that out, my bad. I guess when() doesn't fit this requirement. I guess loop on columns and `selectExpr` will do the work.